# regular expression case with word replacement

Tags: regex, regular-language

I have a part of text and I need to get value with regexp

Text sample

```
> " class="hidden" data-productname="Heltidsulykke udvidet
> 5%"></div></div>
```

I write regexp that match word Heltidsulykke.

```
/data-productname\=\"(.*\p{L}+)sulykke+\s+\p{L}+\p{L}+\s.*\"\>/
```

It is a first step. key that I need to get can bee Heltidsulykke or Fritidsulykke or Børneulykke and ind in case

```
Heltidsulykke (-> Value should be "One")
Fritidsulykke (-> value should be "Two")
Børneulykke (-> value should be "Three")
```

So, the result shoud be "One", "Two" or "Three".

Comment: Please read up on formatting. If you knew more about that you would not even have to cheat around the requirments for more prose around the code-formatted text. Start by taking the [tour]. (It is a link, click it please.)

Comment: Never saw that button like this before. Nice job!